# Ignoring spaces between words - an SQL question

Tags: sql

I want to grab from a db a record with name='John Doe'.

I'd like my query to also grab 'John(4 spaces between)Doe','John(2 spaces betwewen)Doe' etc. (at least one space however).

I'd also like that the case won't matter, so I can also get 'John Doe' by typing
'john doe' etc.

Comment: If the database had been provided, I'd have provided an answer that used lower & substringing to break out the firstname/lastname in an inline view...

Comment: Sorry to be "post-facto", and I understand we do not always control the data flows, but, this is a typical case where simple data content normalization (not normalization in the relation DB sense) would be useful, and avoid all this query time nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lower(NAME) like 'john%doe%'
```

use like with wildcards (e.g. %) to get around the spaces and the lower (orlcase) to be case insensitive.

EDIT:
As the commenters pointed out, there are two shortcomings within this solution.

First: you will select "johnny doe" or worse "john Eldoe", or worse, "john Macadoelt" with this query, so you'll need extra filtering on the application side.

Second: using a function can lead to table scans instead of index scans. This may be avoided, if your dbms supports function based indexes. See [this Oracle example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/FunctionBasedIndexes.php)

Comment: Attention, however, this will also yield entries like "johnny doe" or worse "john Eldoe", or worse,  "john Macadoelt" etc..

Comment: Adding a space on either side of the first % will solve some of the problems mentioned however.

Comment: @mjv: excellent point, probably best to replace all spaces with empty strings and compare with 'johndoe'

Comment: Another suggestion (if applicable/possible) is to have the underlying table/column be case insensitive, _at the level of SQL_, hence avoiding the lower() call, which has many negative effects on the query performance (including the possible need to scan the whole table / index, depending on specific dbms/version)

Comment: @kurosch yes/right (of sorts...) I noted that my idea of the % on either side may disqualify the good boy on the block i.e. the normalized "john doe" (only one space not two!).  On the other hand, your suggestion to remove all spaces is both computationally expensive (and further cause scans), as well as semantically wrong: ex: `"Alric Hardson"` vs. '"AlRichard Son"` vs. `"Al Richardson"` These "simple ones" can be tricky can't they ;-)

Comment: While we're at it, might as well point out that storing first_name and last_name as separate uppercase fields is a pretty standard way to avoid all of these problems.

Comment: You always could do more filtering within the application, so fetching to much results is better then fetching to few. Secondly: yes, using a function can lead to table scans instead of indexes. To get around this, you might create a function based index for this.

Answer (score 2):

If your database has Replace function

```
Select * From Table
Where Upper(Replace(name, ' ', '')) = 'JOHNDOE'
```

The rest of these will return rows where the middle part between John and Doe is anything, not just spaces...

if your database has left function and Reverse, Try either

```
Select * From Table
Where left(Upper(name), 4) = 'JOHN' 
   And Left(Reverse(Upper(name), 3)) = 'EOD'
```

else use substring and reverse

```
Select * From Table
Where substring(Upper(name), 4) = 'JOHN' 
   And substring(Reverse(Upper(name), 3)) = 'EOD'
```

or Like operator

```
Select * From Table
Where Upper(name) Like 'JOHN%DOE'
```

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL:

```
select user_name from users where lower(trim(user_name)) regexp 'john[[:blank:]]+doe' = 1;
```

Explanation:

In the above case the user_name matches the regular expression john(one or more spaces)doe. The comparison is case insensitive and trim takes care of spaces before and after the string.

In case the search string contains special characters, they need to be escaped. More in mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

In sql you can use wildcards, that is a character that stands in place of other characters. for example:

```
select * from table where name like 'john%doe'
```

will select all names that start with john and end with doe no matter how many characters in between.

[This article](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_wildcards.asp) explains more and gives some options.

Comment: As with the accepted answer, be aware this will also return a lot of results you might not be expecting (john mordoe, for example)

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard will match on zero characters, so if you want at least one space then you should do

```
select * from table where lower(name) like 'john %doe'
```

Comment: That will also match 'John Uberdoe'.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(NAME,'( ){2,}', ' ') = 'JOHN DOE';
```

No false positives like 'john mordoe' etc.